# Android - read and write simple text files to internal memory

Tags: android, file

I have searched a lot but it seems older answers are wrong as storage seems to have changed from data/data and permission WRITE_INTERNAL_MEMORY is no longer available.  I am using Eclipse.
I have a multi-choice test and want to store the status of the answers a user has given:
N = not attepmpted, C = Correct last time, I = Incorrect last attempt

Therefore the file needs to be re-writeable - will be read as an array and then the array with new status will be over-written.

The code to write the file on first run is - you can see I've just changed it to write "N" now rather than lines of "N" as needed.  There is also a single-line txt file to store the user id:

```
public void RunFirst(View view) throws IOException{
         //need to initialise file as a list of N's:
         count = 0;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         while(count<4){
         sb.append("N");
         sb.append("\n");
         count = count +1;
         };
         NsString = sb.toString();
         String progfile = "userprogress.txt";

         try {
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(progfile);
              fos = openFileOutput(progfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              fos.write(NsString.getBytes());
              fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
         // read userID
 TextView usrID = (TextView)      findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameInput);
         userID = usrID.getText().toString();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome" + userID, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         //save userID
         String usridfile = "userid.txt";
         try{
             FileOutputStream fosuserid = new FileOutputStream(usridfile);
         fosuserid = openFileOutput(usridfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         fosuserid.write(userID.getBytes());
         fosuserid.close();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "filesaved", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
```

To read from the file:

```
private void readprogressfile(){
    //@Override

    try
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "b4 file", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        InputStream input = openFileInput("userprogress.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
        BufferedReader buffrdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
        userprog = new String [4];
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        count = 0;
        line = null;
        while(count <4){
            input.read(buffer);
            line = new String(buffer);
            userprog[count]= line;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status:" + count + userprog[count], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };
        input.close();

        // byte buffer into a string
        String text= new String(buffer);
        //txtContent.setText(text);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after file", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView showfile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewShowAns);
        showfile.setText("Q status:"+ userprog[qno]);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();}
    }



;
    }
```

Comment: what is the question?  what is the problem?   and why the hell you are not using SQLite database instead???

Comment: 1) The question is where to write simple text files - Doesn't seem complex enough to need a database

Answer (score 0):

the fact that `WRITE_INTERNAL_MEMORY` permission is deprecated don't mean that you can't write to internal memory anymore. actually, it's the opposite - Google decided there is no need in any permission to write / create files in your private internal folder.

you can get path to your private application storage folder by the method [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)

this is the perfect place to write your private files, and made especially for that purpose.

as Google wrote in the documentation:

> You don’t need any permissions to save files on the internal storage. Your application always has permission to read and write files in its internal storage directory.

source and more info on - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html